# Memory Problem : potential leak of an object allocated

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode4

when i analyse my projetc, Xcode analyser find some potential leak of an object allocated
but the trouble is that i don't know what it means and how to resolve this

here is a picture of my file,

[image]

and here is the code

```
#import "RoundRect.h"

//
// NewPathWithRoundRect
//
// Creates a CGPathRect with a round rect of the given radius.
//
CGPathRef NewPathWithRoundRect(CGRect rect, CGFloat cornerRadius)
{
    //
    // Create the boundary path
    //
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - cornerRadius);

    // Top left corner
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y,
        cornerRadius);

    // Top right corner
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        cornerRadius);

    // Bottom right corner
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        cornerRadius);

    // Bottom left corner
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y,
        cornerRadius);

    // Close the path at the rounded rect
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

    return path;

}
```

Thanks for your very useful help.

PS: all my projet works fine in the iphone simulator
it's an app, with a tabbar and 4 section, two section are empty yet,
and the two other section are tableview with detail view (data are picked from a plist)
When i test the app on my device, the two empty sections works perfectly, and juste one of the two tableview display the detailview, the second tableview witch works in the simulator did not push the detailview,
what made me mad is that it works fine this morning

A question:
is a plist limited by the data it contain, i mean that if a have a big list for example with 500 dictionary items, can this trouble the good display of the app ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When returning a CF/CG allocation, the function should be prefixed with `Create`.

I.e. rename your function `CreatePathWithRoundRect()` and the analyzer should stop complaining.

Note that you don't want to collude autorelease with CG/CF types;  that is, follow the patterns perpetuated by the framework containing the type of the object returned.  Thus, returning a +1 retain count object from that function makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

About the potential leak:

it seems that the analyzer is interpreting your `NewPathWIth....` method as a convenience constructor; such constructor by convention return `autorelease`s objects. So I guess that yo remove the analyzer warning you should do:

```
 return [path autorelease];
```

whether this is ok with how you are using that return value, I don't know... what I mean is: if you return the object like you do now, you do not need that the called retains it; if you return it autoreleased, the called could need to retain it if it needs it for longer than the current executing method.

As to the plist question, I don't think that there is a limit on plist. The question is what you do with it. If you are creating a table view with 500 rows, that is much, but since a table view is optimized as to how cells are managed, it should be no problem. In any case, more information is needed (and possibly this is a second question to ask S.O.).